# Допустимость двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

> Купил глушилку сотовых телефонов: в маршрутке езжу в тишине.

Допустима ли в этом случае постановка двоеточия?
(Ведь в некоторых случаях постановка тире и двоеточия вариативна.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) *Купил глушилку сотовых телефонов: в маршрутке езжу в тишине.*

(2) *Купил глушилку сотовых телефонов — теперь в маршрутке езжу в* тишине.

**Пояснение**

1) **Тире и двоеточие взаимозаменяемы не всегда.** При разделительной интонации (восходяще — нисходящая, повышение тона — пауза — понижение тона) ставится только **разделительное тире** (двоеточие невозможно), например: Ехал сюда — рожь начинала желтеть. Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил.

2) В заданном предложение при постановке тире **интонация присоединительная** (нисходяще — нисходящая), именно тогда тире легко меняется на двоеточие, имеющее такую же интонацию, только **с большей паузой**.

**Поэтому здесь допустимы как двоеточие, так и тире.** При постановке двоеточия  на значение **следствия** накладывается **поясняющее** значение двоеточия: купил для того, чтобы ездить в тишине.

Answer (score 4):

Считаю, что **лучше все-таки поставить тире.**
Это бессоюзное предложение, в котором во второй его части однозначно указывается следствие того, что описано в первой части (перед второй частью можно вставить союз **так что**).

На выбор тире влияет и то, что по смыслу в предложении, как мне кажется, пропущено наречие **теперь**, которое имеет значение "при изменившихся обстоятельствах, при создавшихся условиях".

**Купил глушилку сотовых телефонов —** [так что] [теперь] **в маршрутке езжу в тишине.**

[Тире между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)

Comment: Да даже если бы шло перечисление всех преимуществ покупки глушилки, то двоеточие и в этом случае было бы сомнительным.

Comment: Пока это просто утверждение (верное или неверное), а где его доказательство? Почему  же нельзя поставить двоеточие?

Comment: Помимо постановки тире вместо двоеточия (оно заместило бы пропущенную логическую связку результата с действием), можно изменить порядок изложения, поставив _двоеточие_ перед раскрытием причины: _В маршрутке (теперь) езжу в тишине: купил глушилку сотовых телефонов._

Comment: @Sharon Двоеточие было бы на месте при такой модификации: _Купил глушилку сотовых телефонов: в маршрутке **люблю ездить** в тишине._

Comment: В вашем примере значение причины выражено явно. В приведенном предложении явным является следствие (купил - езжу), но причина тоже присутствует по смыслу: это объяснение цели покупки. Купил, чтобы ездить в тишине

Answer (score 3):

*Купил глушилку сотовых телефонов: в маршрутке езжу в тишине.*

Допустима, хотя я лично против такой допустимости: логика мысли нарушается, ведь здесь явное следствие. Однако сейчас нет такой строгости, даже Розенталь допускает вариативность:

> Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с
>   причинно-следственными отношениями. Ср.:
>
> Последние дни флажки на карте не двигались: положение оставалось без
>   перемен. (Сим.); А углубляться мы не могли — земля промёрзла. (Гран.).
>   Ср. также: Кажется, Приморью и без того есть чем подивить мир (:
>   —)одни тигры да женьшень чего стоят.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189

Так что грех не воспользоваться, если не запрещено.